# nested mongoose schema save user data format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a register api that has this kind of schema

```
university_period: {
        from: {
            type: Date
        },
        to: {
            type: Date
        }
    },
```

How should I store the data structure? I don't want to split from and to to become 2 fields.

Comment: Why don't you want to use two fields for it?

Comment: You can use `enrolledYear` and `duration`, and calculate `to` on the basis of these two fields. but you gotta have to fields.